# Powershell - Match ID's in a text file against filenames in multiple folders

Tags: powershell

I need to search through 350,000 files to find any that contains certain patterns in the filename. However, the list of patterns (id numbers) that it needs to match is 1000!  So I would very much like to be able to script this, because they were originally planning on doing it manually...

So to make it clearer:

1. Check each File in folder and all subfolders.
2. If the filename contains any of the IDs in the text file then move it to another file
3. Otherwise, ignore it.

So I have the basic code that works with a single value:

```
$name = Get-Content 'C:\test\list.txt'
get-childitem -Recurse -path "c:\test\source\" -filter "*$name*" | 
move-item -Destination "C:\test\Destination"
```

If I change `$name` to point to a single ID, it works, if I have a single ID in the txt file, it works. Multiple items in a list:

```
1111111
2222222
3333333
```

It fails. What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to work? I'm still new to powershell so please be a little more descriptive in any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test fails because it is effectively trying to do this (using your test data).

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "c:\test\source\" -filter "*1111111 2222222 3333333*"
```

Which obviously does not work. It is squishing the array into one single space delimited string. You have to account for the multiple id logic in a different way.

I am not sure which of these will perform better so make sure you test both of these with your own data to get a better idea of execution time.

### Cycle each "filter"

```
$filters = Get-Content 'C:\test\list.txt'
# Get the files once
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "c:\test\source" -File
# Cycle Each ID filter manually
$filters | ForEach-Object{
    $singleFilter
    $files | Where-Object{$_.Name -like "*$singleFilter*"}
} | Move-Item -Destination "C:\test\Destination"
```

### Make one larger filter

```
$filters = Get-Content 'C:\test\list.txt'
# Build a large regex alternative match pattern. Escape each ID in case there are regex metacharacters.
$regex = ($filters | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"
# Get the files once
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "c:\test\source" -File | 
    Where-Object{$_.Name -match $regex} |
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\test\Destination"
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It makes sense. As for which one is more efficient I can't test that at the moment because the Cycle each 'filter' one fails when I run it. ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the
"Move-Item" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
I've tried to goolge the error, it suggests it can't convert between the 2 types and suggests I put the Where clause in brackets, which is already is, so I've hit a dead end there... however, the 2nd one does appear to work on my small test set so I will test more.

Comment: @SysAdminUK I had a syntax error in the first one. Missing a vertical pipe. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I've run it against the files (or rather a copy of them to be on the safe side) and all in all it only took around 30 seconds to match all 350,000 files against all 1000 IDs, so that was plenty quick enough for me. This did the trick and I learned something new. Answer accepted!

Answer (score -1):

try following this [tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692806.aspx) on how to use get-content function. Looks like when you have a multiple line file, you get an array back. you then have to iterate through your array and use the logic you used for only one item

Comment: This should be a comment if nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial too. More knowledge never hurts!